# how to fix "insert multiple times into mysql table with one query "

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

```
$$(document).on('click', '#employee_table tr input[type="checkbox"] ', function() {



    var row = $$(this).closest("tr")[0];
    new_name = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    new_phone = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
    new_order = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    juice_num1 = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    juice_num2 = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
    juice_num3 = row.cells[6].innerHTML;

    $$('#product_out')


 $$('#product_out').on('click', function() {

var sqlpost = "INSERT IGNORE INTO customers_out (name, telephone, order_num, juice1_num, juice2_num, juice3_num) VALUES (' " + new_name + " ',' " + new_phone + " ' ,' " + new_order + " ',' " + juice_num1 + " ',' " + juice_num2 + " ',' " + juice_num3 + " ')";

        connection.query(sqlpost, function(err, result) {

            app.dialog.alert('Successfull insert!');

            $$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            app.views.main.router.updateCurrentUrl('/home_employee/')

        });

    })

});
```

When I press product-out button , the first data insert into customers_out correctly.

But when I choose another cells and hit the button again , it will insert multiple times

and it's will keep time 3 , 4 , 5 ,6 times when every time I select a new cell with checkbox

I checked phpmyadmin and the data is sumbit multiple time except the first data

I want it insert into database only 1 time when I press the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in `employee_table` click function.

Each time you click a checkbox you are generating

`$('#product_out').on('click', function() {`  function.

**So workflow should be like this**

Click `product_out` button.

Pick the checked row (only 1) read its value and save data.

Reset all checked rows.

```
$('#product_out').on('click', function() {

    // Read first checked row
    var row = $('#employee_table tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("tr")[0];
    new_name = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    new_phone = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
    new_order = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    juice_num1 = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    juice_num2 = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
    juice_num3 = row.cells[6].innerHTML;


    // add Detail to Database
    var sqlpost = "INSERT IGNORE INTO customers_out (name, telephone, order_num, juice1_num, juice2_num, juice3_num) VALUES (' " + new_name + " ',' " + new_phone + " ' ,' " + new_order + " ',' " + juice_num1 + " ',' " + juice_num2 + " ',' " + juice_num3 + " ')";

    connection.query(sqlpost, function(err, result) {

        app.dialog.alert('Successfull insert!');

        $$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        app.views.main.router.updateCurrentUrl('/home_employee/')

    });


    // Reset all checkbox checked
    $('#employee_table tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() { this.checked = false; });

});
```

Comment: this works , but I change $('#product_out').on('click', function() {
to 
$$(document).on('click', '#product_out', function() {

because i am using framework 7

thanks bro!